# php regexp how to delete strings after substring

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with regex.
Trying to delete a strings in text started with "(chapter 1)" constractions, but it does't work.

```
$line = preg_replace('/(\(chapter.*$/', '', $line);
```

Text for sample:

```
(charter 1)sample text, sample text.
(charter 2)sample text, sample text.
(charter 3)sample text, sample text.
```

Comment: you're looking for `chapter`, but your sample text has `charter` and your pattern has an unterminated `(` capture group, making for a regex syntax error

Comment: Женя, is it a multiline string, or just several separate strings? Also, what is the expected output for this string/each of the strings? Try `'/^\(charter\h+\d+\).*/m'` if it is a multiline string.

Comment: Maybe `\((charter[^)]+)\).*`. https://regex101.com/r/wB1kC4/2

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/nC6uB3/1. If you put `^`, it will anchor the match at the start of the string (or line if `/m` modifier is used).

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem. Wiktor your post was helpful. Problem in cyrillic text("chapter"-"глава"). Regex doesn't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "(charter 1)sample text, sample text.";
$str = preg_replace("#^\(charter \d*\)#", "", $str);

// output: sample text, sample text.
```